# fragment lifecycle: when "ondestroy" and "ondestroyview" are not called?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

Imagine this scenario: I have a `Fragment` in a `Pager`. I try to switch to other apps, so that the `Activity` owning my pager (and my fragment) will be stopped and temporarily destroyed, eventually.

So, when I come back to my Activity, the `Fragment`'s callbacks `onCreate`, `oncreateview` and so forth are called. But none of the Fragment's `onDestroy` callbacks were called before! It seems that after "onStop" the fragment is destroyed at once. Is it a normal behavior? Is it maybe because the `Activity` is destroyed without a call to its `onDestroy`?

Comment: I would need a call to a `onDestroy` or `onDestroyView` on the `Fragment` because I have a nested fragment in it that I would like to remove in order to be recreated when `onCreateView` is called back

Comment: Related post - [Activity's onDestroy / Fragment's onDestroyView set Null practices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26369905/465053) & [Why implement onDestroy() if it is not guaranteed to be called?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6117341/465053)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Take a look at this question: [Why implement onDestroy() if it is not guaranteed to be called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117341/why-implement-ondestroy-if-it-is-not-guaranteed-to-be-called)

Basically, onDestroy() is only guaranteed to be called if you call finish(). Otherwise, onDestroy() may not be called until the system deems it necessary.  You might want to look at putting your "closing" logic in the onPause() or onStop() instead.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I was already aware of it, but I was still wondering if the `Fragment`'s `onDestroy` wasn't called because of that.
So, you're confirming that the `Fragment`'s `onDestroy` is not called because its `Activity`'s `onDestroy` is not called either. Did I get right?