# Android Fragment onCreateView after onDestroy not called again

Tags: android, fragment, lifecycle, ondestroy

According to the Android fragment lifecycle i would expect that after `onDestroy` the fragment will be recreated, or at least `onCreateView` is called again.

I have an Activity A starting another Activity B for result and Activity B creating a fragment F.

```
public class A extends FragmentActivity {
    ...
    public void onButonClick() {
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
       startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_B);
    }
}

public class B extends FragmentActivity {
    ...

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            ...
            this.currentFragment = Fragment.instantiate(this, name);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(this.view.getFragmentContainerId(), this.currentFragment, taskName);
            transaction.commit();
    }
}

public class F extends Fragment {
   @override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       this.view = new MyView();  
   }

   @override
   public void onResume() {
       this.view.doSomething();  
   }

   @override
   public void onDestroy() {
       this.view = null;
   }

}
```

When the Fragment is created first time everything is ok, the view is shown. Leaving the app (such as going to system settings) has the affect that **`onDestroy` of the fragment is called without `onDestroyView` is being called**, but when i go back to my app **`onCreateView` ist not called again** which causes a NullpointerException because i am instantiating the view only in `onCreateView`.
Resetting the view in `onDestroyView` i think would solve the problem, but i want to know what's going wrong here with the lifecycyle and if i am doing something wrong.

Thanks.

Here is the logcat output.

```
    03-11 11:22:47.565    6594-6594/com.xy.android.app I/ActivityA Perform button click.
    03-11 11:22:47.595    6594-6594/com.xy.android.app V/ActivityA Pausing activity
    03-11 11:22:47.605    6594-6594/com.xy.android.app D/ActivityB Creating activity
    03-11 11:22:48.075    6594-6594/com.xy.android.app V/ActivityB Starting activity
    03-11 11:22:48.105    6594-6594/com.xy.android.app I/ActivityB Resuming activity
    03-11 11:22:48.476    6594-6594/com.xy.android.app I/ActivityB Starting task FragmentF.
    03-11 11:22:48.536    6594-6594/com.xy.android.app I/FragmentF Attached to activity.
    03-11 11:23:02.350    6594-6594/com.xy.android.app I/FragmentF Creating fragment
    03-11 11:23:02.390    6594-6594/com.xy.android.app I/FragmentF Creating view for fragment
    03-11 11:23:02.420    6594-6594/com.xy.android.app V/FragmentF View for fragment created
    03-11 11:23:02.430    6594-6594/com.xy.android.app D/FragmentF Activity created.
    03-11 11:23:02.441    6594-6594/com.xy.android.app V/FragmentF Starting fragment
    03-11 11:23:02.741    6594-6594/com.xy.android.app V/ActivityA Saving activity instance state.
    03-11 11:23:02.761    6594-6594/com.xy.android.app I/ActivityA Stopping activity
    03-11 11:23:07.686    6594-6594/com.xy.android.app V/FragmentF Pausing fragment.
    03-11 11:23:07.696    6594-6594/com.xy.android.app V/ActivityB Pausing    activity
    03-11 11:23:08.517    6594-6594/com.xy.android.app D/FragmentF Save instance state.
    03-11 11:23:08.567    6594-6594/com.xy.android.app D/ActivityB Saving activity instance state.
    03-11 11:23:08.597    6594-6594/com.xy.android.app I/FragmentF **Destroying fragment**
    03-11 11:23:08.627    6594-6594/com.xy.android.app I/ActivityB Stopping activity
    03-11 11:23:14.033    6594-6594/com.xy.android.app V/FragmentF Starting fragment
    03-11 11:23:14.043    6594-6594/com.xy.android.app V/ActivityB Starting activity
    03-11 11:23:14.063    6594-6594/com.xy.android.app I/ActivityB Resuming activity
    03-11 11:23:14.063    6594-6594/com.xy.android.app I/FragmentF **Resuming fragment**
```

Comment: initialize your view in `onViewCreated()` instead of `onCreateView()`

Comment: this.currentFragment = Fragment.instantiate(this, name); Why are you instantaining your fragment like this instead of default constructor? try  F fragment= new F();

Comment: I guess the startactivityForResult() may be a culprit and did you missed super  calls methods you overridden in your fragment?

Comment: From Fragment lifecycle, can be return to `onCreateView` after `onDestroy`?  from `onDestroyView` can return to `onCreateView`.

Comment: @shayanpourvatan what will this cause? can you please provide more details.

Comment: @Vigneshearan.m i checked all overriden methods, i am always calling super calls. I think the way creating a fragment shouldnt be the problem for the lifecycle ?

Comment: Since the code is not complete could you please attach the Logcat here? @Dokumans

Comment: override onDestroy of your Activity B.

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela can you please give more detail in your answer. What should i do in the overriden method? By the way `onDestroy` is already overriden but it is not called (correctly) because the activity is only stopped.

Comment: nothing has to be done, just override ondestroy in your activity class also.

Comment: But onDestroy of the activity is not called, how will an empty onDestroy affect the lifecycle of the fragment if it is not called ?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/21668806/3831557. as per it - if Activity's onDestroy() not called, fragment's onDestroy() won't be called.

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela I am already aware of the link, thanks. Did you have a look at the logcat i provided? `onDestroy` of ActivityB is not called, but `onDestroy` of Fragment and afterwards only `onStart` and `onResume` of the activity and fragment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After investigating some time i finally "solved" the problem by creating the view in `onCreateView` and destroy it in `onDestroyView`, without understanding why the system does not call the callback as described in the sdk documentation.

Comment: Could you share some sample code? I'm having the same problem and am having trouble understanding it.