# EventBus : Activity does not receive event when app is in the background

Tags: android, android-fragments, service, background-process, event-bus

I'm using `EventBus` to communicate between `Activity` and `Service`.
Today I got a problem and don't know why.

1. I have `Activity`, `Fragment` and `Service`. All of them are working fine.
2. In `Activity` and `Fragment` I `registered` them to `Receive` `events` which delivered from `Service`
3. In `Activity` and `Fragment`, I `un-register` them when `onDestroy()` was called.
4. In normal cases, when `Services` delivers `events`, `Fragment` and `Activity` can receive those `events` and work well.
5. But when `App` is pushed on the `background` (by presses Home or Power button), only `Fragment` receives events which delivered from `Service`, and `Activity` does not receive them.
6. I did not do anything in `onPause()` both of `Activity` and `Fragment`.

**Question:**

Is there any explanation for that? And how can I make my `Activity` receives event like `Fragment` did when app is pushed on background?

Comment: Maybe activity's `onDestroy` gets called and it unregisters it.

Comment: Remove `unregister(this);` from your onDestroy method, and try that.

Comment: `I'm using EventBus to communicate between Activity and Service` this is a wrong approach, use "bound local service" pattern instead

Comment: Can you explain why it's wrong approach @pskink

Comment: because of problems you have now? if you press home / back button your activity can be destroyed at any time, so it will not receive any data

Comment: I don't think its fair to completely dismiss eventbus as an option for app/service communication. It just depends on the purpose of the messages. If the app depends on the service's state, then binding is the best option. If the service raises events, then a bus is better. Also, sticky events will let your activity receive events once it is registered again.

Comment: @Vucko: I tried and no affect. Also I believe that onDestroy was not called in this case

Comment: @pskink: it does not explain why Activity did not receive event while Fragment did. I agree with you that activity can be destroyed when app is in background but that time Fragment also be destroyed.

Comment: @Kevin: stickyEvent still not work in this case :(

Comment: so this is a potential bug in Fragments - they should behave as Activities

Comment: I don't think its a bug. Based on these posts [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21668531/is-ondestroy-guaranteed-to-be-called-for-fragments) and [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195641/fragment-lifecycle-when-ondestroy-and-ondestroyview-are-not-called) `onDestroy` is not always going to be called for fragments. I think register/unregister should be in onStart/onStop; not onCreate/onDestroy

Comment: @Kevin both of onDestroy() in fragment and activity was not called in here, I'm sure.

Comment: need to see some sample code

Comment: Can you add a log in onDestroy to see if it is triggered?

Answer (score 18):

In EventBus version 3.0.0 you can use Sticky posts.

This way you can and should unregister EventBus on 'onStop()' to prevent memory leaks and still receive events when App come to foreground.

Post events this way:

```
EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(new MessageEvent("Hello everyone!"));
```

Subscribe events with sticky flag, like this:

```
@Subscribe(sticky = true, threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onEvent(MessageEvent event) {   
    textField.setText(event.message);
}
```

EventBus Documentation:
http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/configuration/sticky-events/

Answer (score 14):

When user presses back/home button, `Activity` can be destroyed anytime and thus you won't be able to receive the data using EventBus. If any how you are trying to receive the data when the `Activity` is in background, it may leak memory and the app will crash.

There can be other approaches to get the data in the `Activity` when user resumes the `activity`.

You can either user `sharedpreferences` or local database to save the results passed be the `service`. And when the user navigates back to the activity, read it from `sharedpreferences` or database.

This way there won't be any issue with memory leakage or data loss.

Edit 1:

It is always recommended to unregister listeners in either `onPause` or `onStop` because the activity does not need those events when it is not in the foreground. And since `onDestroy()` is not guaranteed to be called, thus you could continue receiving broadcasts when the Activity is no longer open.

Comment: I'd like to ask why I can not receive event in Activity while Fragment did?
when Activity was destroyed I had unregister to receive event and I dont need to receive event any more. By my question is why onDestroyed() was not called yet but I still can not receive event.

Comment: what is the last callback till which you are able to receive the event? `onPause` or `onStop`?

Comment: yes, problem just occurs when App is pushed on background. But Fragment work well

Comment: Ok, so let me clarify first. You are able to receive events before `onStop` is called. And you since you are unregistering for events in `onDestroy`, you are expecting events till `onDestroy` is called. Right?

Comment: What if the `activity` is getting killed right after `onStop` but `onDestroy` is not being called. And thus you are unable to receive the events?

Comment: I' not agree with you in this point. Let's talk about normal case, when I just press home button and then event is dispatch, just few sec and that time activity was not destroyed. you can see in my question that at the same time Fragment is receive event and activity is not. That mean all of them still alive here

Comment: okay, when `onStop` has already been called, how are you checking if events are being received by the `activity`?

Comment: This is my answer, but just rephrased. You can see the dates

Comment: Sometimes I need to unregister the bus inside the `onDestroy()` method to ensure that the `Activity` or `Fragment` can receive posted events.

Answer (score 3):

The Activity class provides two lifecycle methods, onStop() and onRestart() when is not visible (background mode), which allow you to specifically handle how your activity handles being stopped and restarted. Unlike the paused state, which identifies a partial UI obstruction, the stopped state guarantees that the UI is no longer visible and the user's focus is in a separate activity (or an entirely separate app).

In order to understand this cycle, take a look a this image that shows the flow when your app goes out of foreground mode.

[image: When the user leaves your activity]

In your case you can handle the issue like this.

- Provide to the user a mechanism to save persistent application data using either local database(Sqlite), sharedPreferences.
- Handle your data persistency on onStop() method.
- When user callback your app, then you will need to restore the data using onRestart() method.

  Here is the way to implement that.

  ```
  public class Calc extends Activity {
  public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
     super.onCreate(state);
     . . .

     // Restore preferences
     SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
     boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false);
     setSilent(silent);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onStop(){
     super.onStop();

    // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
    // All objects are from android.context.Context
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("silentMode", mSilentMode);

    // Commit the edits!
    editor.commit();
  }
  ```

  }

Please read the following documentation from [Android Developer site](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html)

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to guess what you have done which causing this behavior, consider providing some code.

But what is obvious is that you have some design flaws.

You must unregister from any event bus or listener in your ui components like Activities or Fragments when user navigates back from the app, if you don't, there is a good chance to leak your activity and all of the resources which it holds.

You should store any data which you receive or calculate in your background service to a file or database, when user open or reopen your app you should check for that data and act on it.

Answer (score 2):

Needs more codes or examples to properly help you. But try the following.

1. Are your activities extended from a baseActivity? and if so remove the onDestroy eventbus unregister code and check.
2. In developer options, check whether the don't keep activities option is unchecked.
3. Pressing back will kill your app anyway unless u have overridden the back event.