# Android Memory Leak When Passing A Fragment

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-vision

I have this code and Iam using the Barcode Google API Vision. When i open the Fragment and rotate the device many times 6 or more, i see in the Dump Heap that many instances remain in memory (see pic.) Even after i do a forced Garbage Collection they stay the same. In my code below i dont see any memory leaks.

***Image is after GC***
[image]

> The weird part is that some devices only show 1 instance of the
>   classes after GC which is normal.

```
Emulator API 27  : NO MEMORY LEAKS
Samsung j500FN   : NO MEMORY LEAKS
Xiaomi mi8       : Memory Leak
Galaxy Tablet E  : Memory Leak
```

**MainActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            Fragment sf = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Scanner");
                transaction.add(R.id.root, new Scanner(), "Scanner");
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit(); 

        }
    });
}
```

**Scanner**

```
public class Scanner extends Fragment{

public SurfaceView cameraView;
public BarcodeDetector barcode;
public CameraSource cameraSource;
private SurfaceHolder.Callback cameraCallback;
private ActivityScanBinding mbinding;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("ActivityScan","onCreate");
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.d("ActivityScan","onCreateView");

    mbinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.activity_scan, container, false);


    mbinding.getRoot().setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }

    });
    cameraView = mbinding.getRoot().findViewById(R.id.cameraView);

    return mbinding.getRoot();
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    Scan();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    Log.d("ActivityScan","Destroyed");
    if(barcode!=null) {
        barcode.release();
        Log.d("barcode","Released");
    }
    if(cameraSource!=null) {
        cameraSource.release();
        Log.d("cameraSource ","Released");
    }
    if(cameraView!=null) {
        removeCameraViewCallback();
    }

    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}



public void Scan(){

    cameraView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);

    barcode = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(getActivity())
            .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE)
            .build();

        if(!barcode.isOperational()){
            return;
        }


    cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(getActivity(), barcode)
            .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
            .setRequestedFps(24)
            .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
            .setRequestedPreviewSize(1920,1080)
            .build();

    cameraCallback = new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    cameraSource.start(cameraView.getHolder());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            cameraSource.stop();
        }
    };

    cameraView.getHolder().addCallback(cameraCallback);

    barcode.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {

        @Override
        public void release() {}

        @Override
        public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
            final SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes =  detections.getDetectedItems();
            if(barcodes.size() > 0){

            }
        }
    });


}

public void removeCameraViewCallback(){
    cameraView.getHolder().removeCallback(cameraCallback);
}
}
```

Please see my code and let me know if there is a memory leak.

Leak Canary shows this:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why you're releasing `barcode` and `cameraSource` in `onDestroy` method?
According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17195813/3569545) `onDestroy()` method could be skipped and **not** called. Maybe `onStop()` is more proper place to release resources? And acquire them in `onStart()` respectively.

```
@Override
public void onStop() {

    Log.d("ActivityScan","Destroyed");
    if(barcode!=null) {
        barcode.release();
        Log.d("barcode","Released");
    }
    if(cameraSource!=null) {
        cameraSource.release();
        Log.d("cameraSource ","Released");
    }
    if(cameraView!=null) {
        removeCameraViewCallback();
    }

    super.onStop();
}
```

Also, do not pass `Activity` when creating `BarcodeDetector` and `CameraSource`, and pass `ApplicationContext` if possible.

Comment: I checked everytime in the logs and the destroy method was called everytime.

Comment: Also check official google code in destroy method https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/barcodereader/BarcodeCaptureActivity.java

Comment: @Nick, you have checked the `Activity.onDestroy` while I was talking about the `Fragment.onDestroy`

Comment: And the Fragment's onDestroyed is called also everytime, i checked it.

Comment: @Nick, maybe you shouldn't pass an `Activity` when creating barcode and camera source, do they accept application context?

Comment: That is what iam reading now. Camera Source accepts also an application context (see google docs from the above link). I will give it a try.

Comment: So the answer is to pass application context to barcode and camera source