# Google Maps MapsView leaking

Tags: java, android, google-maps, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I´ve added a Google Maps MapView to a Fragment in Android. Until now it is a clear Map without any Markers, Options or anything else. Nevertheless whenever I leave the Fragment the app has a memory leak.

I´ve already tried all proposed solutions that I have found like attaching the MapView to the Fragment Lifecycle, setting it no null in `onDestroyView()` and so on but the memory leak still prevails.

The current code looks like this:

**fragment_map.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MapViewFragment.java**

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        mMapView = view.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mMapView.onResume();

        MapsInitializer.initialize(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getApplicationContext());

        mMapView.getMapAsync(googleMap -> {
            mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        });

        return view;
    }

@Override
public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();
    }

@Override
public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mMapView.onPause();
    }

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
        mGoogleMap.clear();

        mMapView.onDestroy();
        mGoogleMap = null;
        mMapView = null;
        super.onDestroyView();
    }
```

The **leak trace** looks like this:

```
    ┬
    ├─ com.google.android.gms.internal.location.zzat
    │    Leaking: NO (it's a GC root)
    │    ↓ zzat.zzda
    │           ~~~~
    ├─ com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.ListenerHolder
    │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
    │    ↓ ListenerHolder.zajl
    │                     ~~~~
    ├─ com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.ListenerHolder$ListenerKey
    │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
    │    ↓ ListenerHolder$ListenerKey.zajk
    │                                 ~~~~
    ├─ package.fragments.MapViewFragment$1
    │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
    │    Anonymous subclass of com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback
    │    ↓ MapViewFragment$1.this$0
    │                        ~~~~~~
    ╰→ package.fragments.MapViewFragment
    ​     Leaking: YES (RefWatcher was watching this and Fragment#mFragmentManager is null and Fragment#mFragmentManager is null)
    , retainedHeapSize=null), LeakingInstance(referenceKey=3a478407-69a0-4916-8035-42c2bfd2af4e, referenceName=, instanceClassName=android.widget.RelativeLayout, watchDurationMillis=123593, retainedDurationMillis=118589, exclusionStatus=null, leakTrace=
    ┬
    ├─ com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.q
    │    Leaking: NO (it's a GC root)
    │    Thread name: 'RenderDrive'
    │    ↓ thread q.f
    │               ~
    ├─ com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.n
    │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
    │    ↓ n.k
    │        ~
    ├─ com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.api.y
    │    Leaking: YES (View detached and has parent)
    │    View#mParent is set
    │    View#mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
    │    View.mWindowAttachCount=1
    │    ↓ y.mParent
    ├─ android.widget.FrameLayout
    │    Leaking: YES (y↑ is leaking and View detached and has parent)
    │    View#mParent is set
    │    View#mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
    │    View.mWindowAttachCount=1
    │    ↓ FrameLayout.mParent
    ├─ com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    │    Leaking: YES (FrameLayout↑ is leaking and View detached and has parent)
    │    View#mParent is set
    │    View#mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
    │    View.mWindowAttachCount=1
    │    ↓ MapView.mParent
    ╰→ android.widget.RelativeLayout
    ​     Leaking: YES (RefWatcher was watching this)
    ​     View#mParent is null
    ​     View#mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
    ​     View.mWindowAttachCount=1, retainedHeapSize=null)])
```

However I´ve already tried moving the lifecycle methods around from `onDestroy` to `onDestroyView` and so on.

The memory leak is about 1 to 2 MB every time I leave the MapFragment.
I hope this leak can be fixed, but I don´t have any idea what to try anymore.

Comment: First step is to confirm destroy(destroyView) is called by a breakpoint or log the  method - destroy is not guaranteed to be called.  Some info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17195813/2711811.

Comment: I´ve already checked this and the `onDestroy(View)` methods are being called repsectively the memory leak is still there when the `onDestroy(View)` methods were called.

Comment: Is there any solution to fix this memory leak ?

Comment: Any solution @MaximilianSpeicher?

Comment: @ysfcyln No I haven't a solution back then, but haven't tried recently.

Comment: As a workaround, I add `mMapView.removeAllViews()` to `onDestroyView()` and no more leaks happened.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid memory leaks in map view,should add following things on fragment's `onDestroyView`.

```
 @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        googleMap.clear()
        mMapView.removeAllViews()
        mMapView?.onDestroy()
        super.onDestroyView()
    }
```