# When would Fragment's onDestroyView be called, but it wouldn't be destroyed?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Looking at a Fragment's lifecycle, I am not sure about the scenarios that can happen here.
There are 2 possible ways to go when a Fragment stops being active.

1. call the appropriate callbacks, destroy view and then destroy the fragment
2. call the callbacks, destroy view, but keep the fragment itself alive

Which of the two alternatives is done in which situations? What decides which of them?
If a fragment is added to the backstack, then removed/replaced, why not throw it away? Why keep it?

Edit: it dawned on me, could it be dependant on whether the fragment is retained or not?

[image]

Comment: change orientation then log in the lifecycle methods and check one yourself one situation.

Comment: Related posts - [Activity's onDestroy / Fragment's onDestroyView set Null practices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26369905/465053), [fragment lifecycle: when “ondestroy” and “ondestroyview” are not called?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17195641/465053), & [Why implement onDestroy() if it is not guaranteed to be called?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6117341/465053)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It seems to all depend on whether the fragment is retained or not. When the fragment is retained, then after onDestroyView comes onCreateView.

When the fragment is retained (i.e. setRetainInstance(true)), then the log while rotating the devicelooks like this:

```
com.example.FragmentLifecycleTestApp W/MainFragment﹕ onAttach
com.example.FragmentLifecycleTestApp W/MainFragment﹕ onCreate
com.example.FragmentLifecycleTestApp W/MainFragment﹕ onCreateView
com.example.FragmentLifecycleTestApp W/MainFragment﹕ onActivityCreated
com.example.FragmentLifecycleTestApp W/MainFragment﹕ onStart
com.example.FragmentLifecycleTestApp W/MainFragment﹕ onResume
com.example.FragmentLifecycleTestApp W/MainFragment﹕ onPause
com.example.FragmentLifecycleTestApp W/MainFragment﹕ onStop
com.example.FragmentLifecycleTestApp W/MainFragment﹕ onDestroyView
com.example.FragmentLifecycleTestApp W/MainFragment﹕ onDetach
com.example.FragmentLifecycleTestApp W/MainFragment﹕ onAttach
com.example.FragmentLifecycleTestApp W/MainFragment﹕ onCreateView
com.example.FragmentLifecycleTestApp W/MainFragment﹕ onActivityCreated
com.example.FragmentLifecycleTestApp W/MainFragment﹕ onStart
com.example.FragmentLifecycleTestApp W/MainFragment﹕ onResume
```

But when it is not retained, it goes like this:

```
com.example.FragmentLifecycleTestApp W/MainFragment﹕ onAttach
com.example.FragmentLifecycleTestApp W/MainFragment﹕ onCreate
com.example.FragmentLifecycleTestApp W/MainFragment﹕ onCreateView
com.example.FragmentLifecycleTestApp W/MainFragment﹕ onActivityCreated
com.example.FragmentLifecycleTestApp W/MainFragment﹕ onStart
com.example.FragmentLifecycleTestApp W/MainFragment﹕ onResume
com.example.FragmentLifecycleTestApp W/MainFragment﹕ onPause
com.example.FragmentLifecycleTestApp W/MainFragment﹕ onStop
com.example.FragmentLifecycleTestApp W/MainFragment﹕ onDestroyView
com.example.FragmentLifecycleTestApp W/MainFragment﹕ onDestroy
com.example.FragmentLifecycleTestApp W/MainFragment﹕ onDetach
com.example.FragmentLifecycleTestApp W/MainFragment﹕ onAttach
com.example.FragmentLifecycleTestApp W/MainFragment﹕ onCreate
com.example.FragmentLifecycleTestApp W/MainFragment﹕ onCreateView
com.example.FragmentLifecycleTestApp W/MainFragment﹕ onActivityCreated
com.example.FragmentLifecycleTestApp W/MainFragment﹕ onStart
com.example.FragmentLifecycleTestApp W/MainFragment﹕ onResume
```

Comment: Great thanks for the idea of `setRetainInstance(true)`! In my case, it caused `onDestroyView` not calling when activity with fragment was closed. And when reopening that activity `onDestroyView` from old instance was called after `onCreateView` of new instance.

Comment: @ArtemMostyaev ,hey  I need your little help  I am also facing the same issue ,onDestroyView from old instance was called after onCreateView of new instance . Could you please suggest  me way to solve this

Comment: @Vivek Do not rely too much on `onDestroyView`. It is rarely used as all unused objects can be automatically collected by GC. If you really need it, you can move your code to `onPause` and use `onPause/onResume` pair to save/load state.

Answer (score 14):

Take a look on the diagram:

[image: States of Activity, Fragment and Fragment Manager]

This is the explicit visualization of all lifecycle states. Enjoy.

Comment: What about DialogFragment? When does onDismiss occur on this chart? Same as onDestroy? Or same as onDestroyView? Or something else?

Answer (score 2):

When the fragment is retained (i.e. setRetainInstance(true)),

if setRetainInstance(true) Then :- OnDestroy() is not called 
and again  open fragemnt then onCreate() is not called

but when setRetainInstance(false)  :- then fragment all lifecycle is called