# Fragment manager functioning

Tags: android, android-fragments

Suppose I have added three fragments :
`A`, `B` and `C` in a transaction and I commit the same. After commiting, `onResume()` methods for `A`, `B` and `C` are called successively.

Then, further I use replace function to replace it with a new instance of second fragment.

What I observed is:
`FragmentA` is destroyed 
`FragmentC` is destroyed
`FragmentB` is calling `onStop()` and not `onDestroy()`

A new instance of `FragmentB` is created and its `onCreate()` method is called.

My question is why is `onDestroy()` for `FragmentB` is not called?

Comment: Can i get the code of replace fragments of these three fragments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onDestroy` is not guaranteed to be called. This is true for both `Activity` and `Fragment`.

Take a look at here for more information:

[fragment lifecycle: when "ondestroy" and "ondestroyview" are not called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195641/fragment-lifecycle-when-ondestroy-and-ondestroyview-are-not-called)

[Why implement onDestroy() if it is not guaranteed to be called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117341/why-implement-ondestroy-if-it-is-not-guaranteed-to-be-called)